# Keyboard keeps dismissed every-time its open in react native android

Tags: react-native

In my application i have implemented several TextInput and everything was working fine in iOS, However, in android whenever i click on text input keyboard display then close directly before even typing anything.

I tried in several screens in the app and in every screen same issue happened, I even i tried to just import TextInput in full screen without warping it with any other component but same issue.
I am not sure the issue caused by what or how even to debug it.

I hope someone can lead me to a solution.

**UPDATE**
After debugging looks like the issue is caused by `@react-navigation` library. When importing TextInput outside the `NavigationContainer` it works fine.

Example to produce:

- Screen where i import TextInput

  ```
   const TestScreen = () => {
      return (
        <TextInput
          label="Phone number"
          mode="outlined"
          theme={{colors: {primary: COLORS.primary}}}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          left={<TextInput.Icon name="phone" />}
        />
      );
    };
  ```
- Tabs Navigator

```
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
         tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: COLORS.primary,
           inactiveTintColor: COLORS.darkgray,
            showLabel: false,
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Test" component={TestScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="User" component={Profile} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

- Navigation Container

```
     <NavigationContainer theme={theme} onReady={() => RNBootSplash.hide()}>
              <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{   
                  headerShown: false,
                }}
                initialRouteName={'Home'}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
```

Versions:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
"react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
```

Comment: Code snippet please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line in AndroidManifest.xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"

OR
Downgrading the react native screens version to
"react-native-screens": "3.4.0"

Comment: Thanks salman, the first option worked for me